# Tedious Checkout (Solution with Spring)

Tags: java, spring, checkstyle, pmd

I have worked in some web project based in Spring Framework, and I always find the same PMD/Checkstyle problems cause of  complexity level :(. Here an easy example:

We define the parent class.

```
public Class ObjectA(){
    private ObjectB objectB;

    public ObjectB getObjectB(){
         return objectB;
    }
}
```

Second we defined the child class.

```
public Class ObjectB(){
    private String str;

    public String getStr(){
         return str;
    }
}
```

Now I get from a ObjectA the value of String "str", only if not is empty, but I have to check that all object are not nulls.

First Solution (4 conditions)

```
    if(objectA != null 
       && objectA.getObjectB() != null
       && objectA.getObjectB().getStr() != null 
       && !objectA.getObjectB().getStr().isEmpty()){
       // Do something...
    }
```

Second solution with StringUtils from Spring (3 conditions)

```
    if(objectA != null 
       && objectA.getObjectB() != null
       && StringUtils.hasText(objectA.getObjectB().getStr())){
       // Do something...
    }
```

I want to know if exists some method in Spring to check if ObjectB in ObjectA is not null, and the method must check that ObjectA is not null too.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

It is all about encapsulation basically chaining getters is an anti-pattern (imho).

You should encapsulate part of this in `ObjectA`, you should provide a `getstr` method and remove the `getObjectB()` method.

```
public class ObjectA {
    private ObjectB objectB;


    public String getstr() {
       return objectB != null ? objectB.getstr() : null;
    }
}
```

Now your other code would simply be.

```
if (objectA != null && StringUtils.hasText(objectA.getstr()) { ... }
```

Comment: It could be a solution, but you have to add those methods in parent class. I would prefer a general method to obtain B from A, for example some class Utils class with this getObjFromObj(Object target, String fieldName), and I want to know if exists in Spring this Utility.

Comment: That is what OO is about encapsulation (amongst others). The [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) is all about this. Your object using ObjectA should only know about ObjectA, it shouldn't know about all the collaborating objects ObjectA uses. It is about good/better design. It also makes your code less brittle.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the null checking, by using the @NonNull Lombok's annotation.

Take a look at this:

http://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull.html